# Access Vercel generated preview URL from Nextjs

Tags: next.js, auth0, vercel

Hi I'm deploying a Nextjs 13 app to Vercel and I need to get the Preview generated URL from my code.
As the Vercel documentation says:

> Whenever a new deployment is created, Vercel will automatically
> generate a unique URL which you can use to access that particular
> deployment

So, for example, my deployments URLs look like:

- https://my_first_website-328o7ajnd-my_name-projects-289838be.vercel.app/
- https://my_first_website-468i21dnd-my_name-projects-289838be.vercel.app/
- https://my_first_website-33jfk78aa-my_name-projects-289838be.vercel.app/

and so on...

Where can I find this URL? Is it available among Vercel System Environment Variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Unique URLs are available as Environment Variables ([reference](https://vercel.com/docs/projects/environment-variables/system-environment-variables)). They can be accessed at runtime and build time with `process.env.VERCEL_URL`, and they will be in the format of `example-abc123.vercel.app`. Be careful to not use those URLs for production workloads or importing assets, for example, this should never be used:

```
<script src="https://example-123abc.vercel.app/myscripts.js"></script>
```

You can read more about others automatically generated URLs it in the [Vercel Docs](https://vercel.com/docs/deployments/generated-urls)

Comment: Can you provide the relevant information in your answer? Now just about your entire answer is hidden behind links.

Comment: What do you mean hidden? I am referencing the official documentation here. There is nothing hidden...